# Resource of precoded characters and numbers for use in pbm files (Portable Bitmap)

Tags: c++, c, image

I need to generate .pbm pictures including numbers and characters.

Does anybody know where to find precoded numbers and characters so I won't have to write them myself like the 'J' on [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)?

I am coding in C and C++

Answer (score 0):

If you put something like `"public domain" & "pixel font"` into your favorite search engine, you'll find a number of websites with fonts like [dafont](http://www.dafont.com/bitmap.php). Make sure the font you like has a license allowing you to use it as you want.

If the font comes as a picture or a collection of pictures, you can write a simple tool to extract individual pixels from them and convert them into C arrays or whatever you need.